# scrollTo not working when want to scroll to the top

Tags: javascript, scroll

I just want to automatically scroll top page so I've used

```
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

but its not working. The following code is working fine for my problem but i want to scroll top when user click

```
// Javascript to enable link to tab
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href=#'+url.split('#')[1]+']').tab('show') ;
} 

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
})
```

Comment: `window.scrollTo(0,0);` Works fine for most cases, could you provide more detail? where abouts in the code did you place it?

Comment: @james
open itsolworks.com and scroll down to footer you will see services on left side in footer just click on any service it will redirect to you services.php and same tab but page could now scroll top....

var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href=#'+url.split('#')[1]+']').tab('show') ;
} 

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
window.scrollTo(0,0);
})

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem....

For me the solution was to set a height on the main element in the content.  Then `window.scrollTo(0,0);` worked for me again.

If that does not fix it, you could also try:

```
document.getElementById('header').scrollIntoView();
```

And if that does not resolve your issue, you can try this also:

```
document.body.scrollTop = 0;
```

I would recommend you check the height property first.